# Is it possible to pass multiple WMS layer to a processing script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Is it possible to pass multiple WMS layers as parameters to a QGIS 3 processing script, similar to QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers but using WMS or WFS Layer? QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers does only accept Raster-/Vectorlayers depending on the defined SourceType in QgsProcessing.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with the layers, especially if they're WMS-layers.

Comment: we are planing a tool that packs layers into a geopackage, like the existing "package layer" tool (folder Database). the user should be able to select also wms or wfs layers depending of the layertree in his project